# Spring integration asynchronous communication synchronous response

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, asynchronous, spring-integration

I currently have an inbound https gateway. In the internal processing of the request from http gateway I  call multiple http web services. Currently as I monitored from a debug point if I am calling 4 web services from a publish-subscribe channel they are executed one after another. Then after 4 of the services are called one by one they are aggregated and a response is returned. The problem here is that there is the potential to be N number of calls, so essentially there could only be 2 http web service calls or there could be even 100. In order to solve this I added a task executor to the publish subsce channel as follows

```
<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="ta-htl-data-router-channel" apply-sequence="true" task-executor="pool" />

<task:executor id="pool" pool-size="10"/>
```

Then while the web router channel subscribers are executed synchronously the http inbound gateway stops working properly, that is I get the following error message

```
Reply message received but the receiving thread has already received a reply
```

And I get a response json string TO DOWNLOAD instead of it being showed in the browser as a respone.

How I can I call multiple external web services asynchronously and send an aggregated response to the http inbound gateway. Therefore while the overall http inbound gateway request to response occurs synchronously the calling of the multiple external web services internally happens asynchronously to reduce the processing time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"` on your `<task:executor>`.

The issue is may be in those `long-running` call for the web services, hance if you have more than 10 concurrent tasks, all others will be `ABROTED` by default.

Comment: Also on another note is it that I have up to 10 concurrent tasks PER http request? OR if I get 20 concurrent inbound http requests they altogether have to use the same threadpool of 10 threads then

Comment: How would I make it ten threads per task executor, or in the case this is impossible what would be the best practice or guidelines for selecting the thread pool number. Also in addition to this when the whole thread pool is used up how would I prevent the other execution attempts being aborted and instead have them force for the thread pool to free up then

Comment: See my answer: `rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"` is the best compromise. Anyway it would be bad to scale your pull size according to the incomming request. There should wholesome compromise between your CPUs and concurrent threads.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an `<aggregator/>` to combine the results into a list, and some transformer aftrer that to construct the response from the results; the original http thread will be waiting for the result, according to the `reply-timeout`.